# UMDF: Access device registry key inside a EVT_WDF_TIMER callback function

Tags: driver, wdf, umdf

I am having issues with a UMDF driver retrieving data stored in the device registry from a `EVT_WDF_TIMER`  callback function. Such callback function only has `WDFTIMER` object as its sole parameter. To be able to access registry in UMDF, `WdfDeviceOpenRegistryKey` requires a pointer to the `WDFDEVICE` object. Prior to the callback function being called, my `WDFTimer`, which calls the callback function after the timer has elapsed, is created by `WdfTimerCreate`. I have provided the appropriate `WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` as well, one of the attributes being a `WDFOBJECT ParentObject` where I assigned the `WDFDEVICE` object into.

Now, I was hoping I could retrieve the `WDFDEVICE` object I added in `WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`, but it seems inaccessible from the `WDFTIMER` parameter. I am left wondering, is there any way I could retrieve a pointer to my `WDFDEVICE` from the `EVT_WDF_TIMER`  callback function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WdfTimerGetParentObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdftimer/nf-wdftimer-wdftimergetparentobject)  to retrieve the WDFOBJECT.